# How to get user finger print for authentication?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to add a finger print scanner in my android app for authentication. I have searched on google but found finger print support only for android marshmallow. I want to add this for android API version 14 to 23. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Android's Fingerprint Scanner for Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276026/using-androids-fingerprint-scanner-for-application)

Comment: Finger Print Sensor introduced in Android 6.0, Here is the google doc https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html.
Also Finger print Sensor hardware came recently in Android phone so I don't think supporting API version 14 to 23 is useful.

Comment: Samsung API also giving me error or permission but I have given ppermission  <uses-permission android:name= "com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Fingerprint API was added in Marshmallow (API 23). You can still target API 14 with [FingerprintManagerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManagerCompat.html). Pre Marshmallow it behaves as there would be no fingerprint hardware available.