# Steps to integrate bio-metric finger print to android app

Tags: java, android, integration, biometrics

I need finger print authentication in my app. I have no idea about this, so my question is:-
How to connect bio-metric device through USB or Bluetooth and integrate it with my app so that user can scan finger print on that device and my app can receive it as image.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial) , [this](http://willowtreeapps.com/blog/android-fingerprint-apis-an-overview-for-android-app-developers/) , [this](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/introducing-androids-fingerprint-api) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276026/using-androids-fingerprint-scanner-for-application)

Comment: @Jaydroid thanks , but I have gone through these links. for http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial
if (initCipher()) {
        cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
        FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
        helper.fingerprintHandler(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
    }
above code is having error kindly suggest.