# How to add fingerprint authentication on under marshmallow devices

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

Sir, i am trying to add fingerprint authentication in my app. I have Coolpad note 3 lite mobile which support fingerprint authentication and it is running on Android version 5.1 Lollipop. But the problem is how can i authenticate fingerprint in it.
I have seen Android Developers Documentation they said it is possible only on devices running on Marshmallow or above.
So how can i do it on my Device..

That Code i Found on Internet is this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        //Get an instance of KeyguardManager and FingerprintManager//
        keyguardManager =
                (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        fingerprintManager =
                (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        //Check whether the device has a fingerprint sensor//
        if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
            // If a fingerprint sensor isn’t available, then inform the user that they’ll be unable to use your app’s fingerprint functionality//
            textView.setText("Your device doesn't support fingerprint authentication");
        }
        //Check whether the user has granted your app the USE_FINGERPRINT permission//
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // If your app doesn't have this permission, then display the following text//
            textView.setText("Please enable the fingerprint permission");
        }

        //Check that the user has registered at least one fingerprint//
        if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
            // If the user hasn’t configured any fingerprints, then display the following message//
            textView.setText("No fingerprint configured. Please register at least one fingerprint in your device's Settings");
        }

        //Check that the lockscreen is secured//
        if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
            // If the user hasn’t secured their lockscreen with a PIN password or pattern, then display the following text//
            textView.setText("Please enable lockscreen security in your device's Settings");
        } else {
            try { generateKey();
            } catch (FingerprintException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (initCipher()) {
                //If the cipher is initialized successfully, then create a CryptoObject instance//
                cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);

                // Here, I’m referencing the FingerprintHandler class that we’ll create in the next section. This class will be responsible
                // for starting the authentication process (via the startAuth method) and processing the authentication process events//
                FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
                helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fingerprint scanner is not a feature in below Marshmallow (Now available on Android M).

So each company as Samsung, Motorola, HTC create is own API and SDK to access to fingerprint sensor.

[here is the StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276026/using-androids-fingerprint-scanner-for-application)

Or you can use `FingerprintManagerCompat` class of Support Library v4 to support minSdk less than 23.

find more on [Developer Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManagerCompat)

[github sample](https://github.com/AMykich/Android-Fingerprint-API)

As per @Michael comment

Note that `FingerprintManagerCompat` doesn't give you access to any fingerprint sensor that might exist on pre-Marshmallow devices. It only saves you the trouble of checking the API level yourself.

Comment: Note that `FingerprintManagerCompat` doesn't give you access to any fingerprint sensor that might exist on pre-Marshmallow devices. It only saves you the trouble of checking the API level yourself.

Comment: Yes I have mentioned that now, and also I have also written that 'Fingerprint scanner is not a feature in below Marshmallow'

Comment: Note that every manufacturer have their own SDK if the device is below Marshmallow

Comment: Sir can you provide me any tutorial link for FingerprintManagerCompat, Because i am unable to find one in java